# Images deleted after deployment with Elastic Beanstalk (AWS)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have issues with the images I upload on my app.

At begin, the upload works fine and the images are stored in my images folder, but once I deploy a new version of my back-end or every time the server does an upgrade, my folder is deleted and images as well.

I don't know how to makes them be permanent except storing them in 64 bits into my DB, or by building an FTP server dedicated to storing them through a PHP app.

Better ideas are welcome!

Comment: Your folder isn't being deleted, the entire server is being deleted and recreated. That's how Elastic Beanstalk works. You shouldn't store files like that directly on an Elastic Beanstalk server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any assets that exist on disk then you should migrate them to a resilient data store such as [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Servers are not immune to failure, if this occurred at any point then again your images would be lost.

By using S3 you would need to update your source code to reference the S3 bucket URL, with any upload logic replaced to use the [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/) instead using the [putObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) function.